# WampServer suddenly went offline

Tags: wamp, offline

I was using WampServer for my PHP development. Suddenly, it went offline. (It says the wamp server is online but in red color)

I don't use skype, and when I check port 80 used for the wamp server it says port 80 is free.

This is the accesslog for last few hours:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Jun/2013:15:32:47 +0530] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 209
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Jun/2013:15:32:49 +0530] "GET /test/ HTTP/1.1" 200 7
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Jun/2013:15:32:49 +0530] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 209
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Jun/2013:15:33:34 +0530] "POST /phpmyadmin/import.php HTTP/1.1" 200 100380
```

This is the appache_error log:

```
[Wed Jun 12 14:19:48 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/wamp/www/favicon.ico
[Wed Jun 12 14:20:35 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] WordPress database error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'column REGEXP '[0-5]'' at line 1 for query SELECT * FROM wp_skilllist WHERE column REGEXP '[0-5]' made by require('C:\\wamp\\www\\wordpress\\wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('C:\\wamp\\www\\wordpress\\wp-includes\\template-loader.php'), include('C:\\wamp\\www\\wordpress\\wp-content\\themes\\twentytwelve\\Skill_page.php'), test_getproducts, referer: http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=2
[Wed Jun 12 14:20:37 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/wamp/www/favicon.ico
[Wed Jun 12 14:21:04 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] WordPress database error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'column REGEXP '[0-5]+$'' at line 1 for query SELECT * FROM wp_skilllist WHERE First_name LIKE 'Menuka%' AND column REGEXP '[0-5]+$' made by require('C:\\wamp\\www\\wordpress\\wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('C:\\wamp\\www\\wordpress\\wp-includes\\template-loader.php'), include('C:\\wamp\\www\\wordpress\\wp-content\\themes\\twentytwelve\\Skill_page.php'), test_getproducts, referer: http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=2
[Wed Jun 12 14:21:06 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/wamp/www/favicon.ico
[Wed Jun 12 14:21:46 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] WordPress database error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'column REGEXP '^[0-5]+$'' at line 1 for query SELECT * FROM wp_skilllist WHERE First_name LIKE 'Menuka%' AND column REGEXP '^[0-5]+$' made by require('C:\\wamp\\www\\wordpress\\wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('C:\\wamp\\www\\wordpress\\wp-includes\\template-loader.php'), include('C:\\wamp\\www\\wordpress\\wp-content\\themes\\twentytwelve\\Skill_page.php'), test_getproducts, referer: http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=2
[Wed Jun 12 14:21:47 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/wamp/www/favicon.ico
[Wed Jun 12 14:22:01 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/wamp/www/favicon.ico
[Wed Jun 12 15:31:57 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/wamp/www/favicon.ico
```

MySQL error log:

```
130607 10:14:46  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
130607 10:14:47 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 2897277
130607 10:14:47 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '(null)'; port: 3306
130607 10:14:47 [Note]   - '(null)' resolves to '::';
130607 10:14:47 [Note]   - '(null)' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
130607 10:14:47 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
130607 10:14:49 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
130607 10:14:49 [Note] wampmysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.24-log'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
130612 15:37:34 [Note] wampmysqld: Normal shutdown

130612 15:37:34 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
130612 15:37:35  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
```

I tried several articles but I didn't find a solution. My main problem is it was working properly and suddenly stopped working, which is why I included the error logs.

Is there anything I have to do with user permissions for machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very sad, I found that network administrator has removed administrator permission on my machine.
Once I asked him to allow me the rights on machine, I could run wamp server.

If you are in a network and working wamp server goes ofline, please check your rights permission on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

As you could see, you have an error refered to wp_skilllist plugin, probably could be better if you disable this plugin. I ma not completely sure about it, but it is a posibility, cause the line of your log reers to this script
Take care of this line

```
[Wed Jun 12 14:21:46 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] WordPress database error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'column REGEXP '^[0-5]+$'' at line 1 for query SELECT * FROM wp_skilllist WHERE First_name LIKE 'Menuka%' AND column REGEXP '^[0-5]+$' made by require('C:\\wamp\\www\\wordpress\\wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('C:\\wamp\\www\\wordpress\\wp-includes\\template-loader.php'), include('C:\\wamp\\www\\wordpress\\wp-content\\themes\\twentytwelve\\Skill_page.php'), test_getproducts, referer: http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=2
```

There is the problem, as you could see it is refering 'C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-content\themes\twentytwelve\Skill_page.php', tryies to change teh theme

Comment: how to disable that without accessing it? I remove the web site from the www folder though. But I still get the error

Comment: Sure, you are getting the error, cause the database continue there, also, if you remove the www folder the server will go down, cause apache will need the www folder to run, what it is happening now is that the wamp couldnt start, firsts at all you must restore www folder, the remove the plugin on the folder wp-content/plugins and that must be enought

Comment: no no sorry I mean the website in www folder. I didnt remove the www folder.

Comment: I have changed the content of mya nswer, but if you remove the content of www, please paste the new error, cause your logs refers to the line on the php

Comment: I have removed the wordpress folder totally from www folder. I think `130612 15:37:35  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...` gives a message. But I can't figure.

Comment: PLease paste your last mysql log after trying to restart it, mysql error log

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31676/discussion-between-carlos-and-menuwordpress)

Comment: that is what I have given in the question.

Comment: I have not ideas, tryies to disable innodb on your my.ini. ( I am on the chat )